# How to check the CustomEvent detail in a Jest test for an LWC?

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-events, lwc-jest, custom-event

I'm on my first day of writing Jest tests for one of our LWCs, and that component fires an event with some dates included as the event `detail`:

```
@api get selectedDates() {
    return this.selectedSortedDates();
}

handleClick() {
    let afterDates = this.selectedSortedDates();
    const event = new CustomEvent('selectionchange', { detail: afterDates });
    this.dispatchEvent(event);
}
```

This test code (inspired by [How to test LWC onsuccess event handler in Jest](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/260761/how-to-test-lwc-onsuccess-event-handler-in-jest)) works:

```
    const handler = jest.fn();
    element.addEventListener('selectionchange', handler);

    const tueJan28 = element.shadowRoot.querySelector('span[data-day="7331"]');
    tueJan28.click();

    const friJan31 = element.shadowRoot.querySelector('span[data-day="7344"]');
    monFeb10.click();

    // Can check the dates property
    const expecteds = [
        new Date(2020, 0, 28),  // Tue
        new Date(2020, 0, 29),
        new Date(2020, 0, 30),
        new Date(2020, 0, 31),  // Fri
    ];
    expect(element.selectedDates).toStrictEqual(expecteds);

    return Promise.resolve().then(() => {
        expect(handler).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(2);
        // But how to check the event detail here?
        // expect(handler).toHaveBeenCalledWith(... expecteds ...);
    });
```

but I haven't managed to come up with a `toHaveBeenCalledWith` technique that checks the event detail.

`expect(handler).toHaveBeenCalledWith` says this is received:

> {"composed": false, "isTrusted": false, "stopImmediatePropagation":
>   [Function value], "stopPropagation": [Function value]}

Is there a way capture the `detail` of the event and assert its value?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This [Jest Test Patterns and Mock Dependencies](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.unit_testing_using_jest_patterns) includes the answer:

```
    return Promise.resolve().then(() => {
        expect(handler).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(2);
        expect(handler.mock.calls[0][0].detail).toStrictEqual(click0Expecteds);
        expect(handler.mock.calls[1][0].detail).toStrictEqual(click1Expecteds);
    });
```

where the [mock](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-functions.html) property holds the information on the calls made with the first index the call number and the second index the argument number for that call.