# What repositories of LWC Jest tests are publicly available?

Tags: lightning-web-components, lwc-jest

I've been looking at example Jest tests here [trailheadapps / lwc-recipes](https://github.com/trailheadapps/lwc-recipes/tree/master/force-app/main/default/lwc) but don't see examples of e.g.:

- injecting keys
- multiple layers of promises (see "best guess" below)
- factoring out of common test code.
- <strike>or [How to check the CustomEvent detail in a Jest test for an LWC?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/298892/how-to-check-the-customevent-detail-in-a-jest-test-for-an-lwc)</strike>

(This [Jest Test Patterns and Mock Dependencies](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.unit_testing_using_jest_patterns) documentation is worth a read.)

So I am wondering if there are other publicly accessible repositories with more examples of Jest tests for LWCs? (There is plenty of material on Jest: it is the specific patterns of use of LWC and Jest together that I'm looking for.)

Answer (score 1):

I can find these:-

1. [wire-service-jest-util](https://github.com/salesforce/wire-service-jest-util) -  A utility so Lightning Web Component unit tests can control the data provisioned with @wire.
2. [lwc directory of lwc-recipes repo](https://github.com/trailheadapps/lwc-recipes/tree/master/force-app/main/default/lwc) - Many recipes have a **tests** directory with commented jest tests.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Sanket, I already had the second one listed in the question.

Comment: ahh, I thought you were just referring to the documentation there.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a "best guess" at some of these questions that appears to work, but I couldn't figure out how to dispatch a keyboard event that automatically went to the focussed element. Note that `await` on a non-promise automatically adds a wrapping promise.

```
it('has keyboard capability', async () => {

    const element = createElement('c-datepicker', { is: Datepicker });
    element.startYear = 2020;
    element.startMonth = 1;
    element.numberOfMonths = 2;

    element.scheduleStart = SCHEDULE_START;
    element.scheduleMinutes = SCHEDULE_MINUTES;
    element.holidayDates = [];
    element.alreadyRequesteds = new Map();
    element.selectionMode = 'dates';

    document.body.appendChild(element);

    const tueJan14 = element.shadowRoot.querySelector('td[data-day-number="7317"]');
    await tueJan14.focus();
    await tueJan14.dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent('keydown', {'keyCode': ENTER_KEY_CODE}));
    expect(element.selectedDates).toStrictEqual([
        new Date(2020, 0, 14)
    ]);

    const wedJan15 = element.shadowRoot.querySelector('td[data-day-number="7318"]');
    await wedJan15.focus();
    await wedJan15.dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent('keydown', {'keyCode': ENTER_KEY_CODE}));
    expect(element.selectedDates).toStrictEqual([
        new Date(2020, 0, 14),
        new Date(2020, 0, 15)
    ]);
});
```